# Method to tab between Text Boxes in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

Does anyone know of a way to press the 'Tab' key and move between text boxes in Excel (2010)?  The VBA solution I've seen is way too manual, as you need to create code for the 'Tab' event on each text box.

For example, the following would need to be replicated for every TextBox in the workbook:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then TextBox2.Activate
End Sub
```

(The text boxes are NOT part of a VBA form.  They are part of a regular worksheet.)

Thank you,
Don

Answer (score 0):

First Go To Special, select Objects and OK.

Comment: This selects ALL objects, but does nothing to help me tab between the objects.  Unless I'm missing something?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a method that allows the user to type something into any given textbox, press Tab, and have the cursor/selection move to the next textbox.